# Bind localhost to DynDNS address

Tags: networking, router, ip, port-forwarding

I have registered my domain to `dyn.com` so that people can access my `localhost` outside the network.

The address points to my IP address: `85.xxx.xxx.xxx`

In the router I've forwarded the port `85.xxx.xxx.xxx` port `80` to `195.xxx.xx.xx` port `80` which is my `localhost` IP.

But when I type in the domain it only displays router login page.

I can not connect to the `localhost` outside the network.

I really need help.

Comment: Search this website about "NAT hairpin". It sounds like everything is fine with the domain itself.

Comment: sorry but about NAT i did´t understand anything.